Patch or update by search query axios
I have django restframework and control from javascript axios
What I am doing is like this,
  axios.get(`http://localhost:8010/api/myusers/?my_id=${my_id}`).then((res)=>{
    var id = res['data']['results'][0]['id'];
    axios.patch(`http://localhost:8010/api/myusers/${id}/`, {
        phone: 'nice phone',
    }).then((res)=>{
      console.log("patch finish");
    })
  })

Fetch the id by my_id and patch the data.
However I think it is a bit clumsy, it uses twice request.
At first get the id by my_id and change data by id
So, I would like to do this by one request.
How can I make it ?
I tried like this but 405 Method not allowd error
  axios.patch(`http://localhost:8010/api/myusers/?my_id=${my_id}`, {
    phone: 'nice phone2',
  }).then((res)=>{
    console.log("patch finish");
  })

my settings in server
I am using djangorestframework and django filter
class MyUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = sm.MyUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = sl.MyUserSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    search_fields = ['my_id']
    filterset_fields = ['my_id']

class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = sm.MyUser
        fields = ('my_id','phone','id','created_at')


by changing/adding code on the server to patch a given my_id

I tried like this - did you change anything on the server code to allow it? you can't just make random requests and expect the server to change how it functions

No change on server, however the former patch works, what should I change?

what should I change? code on the server - the former patch works because the server understands the request, your made up request is not understood, therefore, the code on the server needs to allow such a request

I updated the article I don't set any things related with method

From django-rest_framework code

# If you want to use object lookups other than pk, set 'lookup_field'.
# For more complex lookup requirements override `get_object()`.
lookup_field = 'pk'
lookup_url_kwarg = None


You can change these parameters in your ModelViewSet (inheriting from GenericViewSet)
So you can make one request directly to the url with 'my_id'.
